# How can I create a WCF Service Application in Visual Studio that does NOT use a Web Server

Tags: visual-studio, wcf

I have a simple task: A program (executable) is supposed to call a function of another program (also executable) with some parameters. Program A is supposed to be started, call the function and then terminate. Program B is legacy program that has a GUI and runs continuously. Both programs run on the same Windows PC and use the .NET Framework. I have no experience in web development and Program B is not supposed to run as a web service! Named pipes seem like a good option.

I researched what the best method would be and wanted to try WCF. The documentation claims that "A service endpoint can be part of a continuously available service hosted by IIS, or it can be a service hosted in an application". From that I understand that I can run Program B as a service without hosting a web server.

However everything I see in Visual Studio seems to presume I want to run a server. Wenn I want to create a new WCF project in Visual Studio the only options are a library or "A project for creating WCF service application that is hosted in IIS/WAS". Once I've created said project the debugger wants me to choose a browser for hosting the service.

In another StackOverflow topic a popular suggestion was using [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20141027055124/http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication) website as a guide and simply removing the http references since the guide is for both named pipes and http. Another indication that it should be possible.

So can someone point me in the right direction? What am I missing? How can I use WCF with nothing related to Web Development involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already been on the way, it is enough to host the web service in Program B, without specifying a web server. this is called a self-hosted WCF. As the link you provided mentioned, the Service host class is used to host the WCF service, which means that we can host the service in the `Console/Winform`, and so on.
Here is an example of hosting the service in a Winform application.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ServiceHost serviceHost = null;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:9009");
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), uri);
            serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), binding, "");
            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior()
            {
                HttpGetEnabled = true
            };
            serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
            System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding mexbinding = MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding();
            serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), mexbinding, "mex");
            serviceHost.Open();

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (serviceHost.State==CommunicationState.Opened)
            {
                this.label1.Text = "Service is running";
            }
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (serviceHost.State==CommunicationState.Opened&&serviceHost.State!=CommunicationState.Closed)
            {
                serviceHost.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string Test();
    }
    public class MyService:IService
    {
        public string Test()
        {
            return DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        }
    }
```

After that, we could consume it by using a client proxy.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/accessing-services-using-a-wcf-client
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Thank you. When I'm in Visual Studio I'd still forces me to choose a web browser for debugging. It will then try to open http://localhost:59125/ and display "This page isn’t workinglocalhost didn’t send any data. 
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"  However, it works just fine if I compile it and run the .exe. So I have accepted your answer.